Does the expansion of the universe cause the universe reach maximum entropy faster than a non expanding universe?
I've seen Does an expanding universe cool down?
So I understand an expanding universe cools down, my question is, does an expanding universe reach maximum entropy faster than a non-expanding universe?
I ask because heat transfer is faster the larger the difference in temperature. What I don't understand at this point: is expanded space colder than the already existing space, causing energy to spread out faster?
Or am I off base and the speed of light limits the speed at which maximum entropy can be reached.

Can you define "entropy of the universe"?

@TobiasFünke did I use wrong terminology? I'm asking from a standpoint of a common explanation that at some point the universe reaches maximum entropy -- "heat death".

See this... I could count a handful of arguments why "entropy of the universe" per se is not well-defined. But as you seem to make the claim that it is a well-defined term, you are in charge to provide a clear definition.

@TobiasFünke you could make that as part of an answer.  I'm not a physicist. I'm subject to what Science educators and popularizers say about these things.

I see. Sorry, I don't have time to write an answer. Long story short: Things are (as usual) very complicated, and one cannot just naively use the concept of entropy (there are actually several such notions which are all called "entropy") and apply it to the whole universe. I think Wikipedia summarizes well some concerns about it. See also this, especially the answer by Ján Lalinský.

@TobiasFünke well thank you for your time, and actually you've expanded my knowledge by even pointing out this problem and giving links.
